# When does an orthomodular projection lattice have a non-trivial centre?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lattice-theory

When does an orthomodular lattice $L$ of projections onto a given Hilbert space have a non-trivial centre $Z(L)$ and what can we generally say about the cardinality of $Z(L)$?

Comment: What do you mean by "projections onto a given Hilbert space"? I inferred from your question that you probably mean "all orthogonal projections on a given Hilbert space". Am I right?

Comment: oh yes, sorry, that is what i meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ Z (L) $ contains the subspaces that are orthogonal or comparable to all the other subspaces in $ L $. So if the Hilbert space has finite dimension $ d $ you can get $2^d $ many elements in $ Z (L) $ with $ L $ of size $2^d $ also. For instance take $ L $ to consist of the coordinate planes in $ R^3$.

Comment: It is not true that the coordinate planes in $R^3$ are orthogonal or comparable to all other subspaces. Proof: take any plane that is *not* among the coordinate planes.

Comment: @GejzaJenča That's not what I was claiming. The question is a bit hard to read but I took it to mean that $L$ is a lattice of projections but not necessarily the lattice of *all* projections. So $L$ corresponds to a set of subspaces closed under intersection and join.